# How to set collation in rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

Im trying to set my db collation to utf8_general_ci

Here is my database.yaml

```
default: &default
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: utf8
    collation: utf8_general_ci
    host: <%= ENV["POSTGRES_HOST"] %>
    port: <%= ENV["POSTGRES_PORT"] %>
    username: <%= ENV["POSTGRES_USER"] %>
    pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
    <<: *default
    database: <%= ENV["POSTGRES_DB_NAME"] %>
    password: <%= ENV["POSTGRES_PASSWORD"] %>
```

When I run `rails db:setup` I get:

```
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::WrongObjectType: ERROR:  invalid locale name: "utf8_general_ci"
: CREATE DATABASE "my_db" ENCODING = 'utf8' LC_COLLATE = 'utf8_general_ci'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure `utf8_general_ci` is a valid postresql collation? I think it's a mysql collation, not postresql. Check postresql docs and look for valid collations first.

Comment: Thanks, im being a moron. Feel free to put it as an answer so i can give you a tick :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`utf8_general_ci` is a MySQL collation, not PostgreSQL. Check Postresql docs for valid collations.